# Selenium server error retreiving new session in jenkins

Tags: selenium

I'm having trouble running on jenkins my selenium tests, when the start the server starts, but says the following:

```
Error retrieving a new session from the selenium server
Connection refused! Is selenium server started?

{ value: 
   { message: 'Unable to create new service: GeckoDriverService\nBuild info: version: \'3.11.0\', revision: \'e59cfb3\', time: \'2018-03-11T20:33:15.31Z\'\nSystem info: host: \'5b4305564fb2\', ip: \'172.17.0.4\', os.name: \'Linux\', os.arch: \'amd64\', os.version: \'4.4.0-1048-aws\', java.version: \'1.8.0_162\'\nDriver info: driver.version: unknown', error: 'session not created' }, status: 33 
}
```

Locally the test work fine either on chrome or firefox, but when they run on the CI the error above happens. Any idea of what I could be doing wrong?

Below error when using firefox
[image: Error displayed]

Below error when using chromedriver
[image]

But when I run the tests as chrome headless the run perfect on CI.

Comment: Isn't the error clear and concise as in `'Unable to create new service: GeckoDriverService\nBuild info: version: \'3.11.0\', revision: \'e59cfb3\', time: \'2018-03-11T20:33:15.31Z\'\nSystem info: host: \'5b4305564fb2\', ip: \'172.17.0.4\', os.name: \'Linux\', os.arch: \'amd64\', os.version: \'4.4.0-1048-aws\', java.version: \'1.8.0_162\'\nDriver info: driver.version: unknown', error: 'session not created' }, status: 33`? Update the question with your _code trials_ and text formatted error stack trace please.

Comment: I'm not understanding the error, locally on my machine works fine but when it runs on CI (jenkins) this happens.